# Como adicionar um time(contador de tempo) em Game

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consegui esse joguinho em *HTML + JavaScript + CSS* a um tempo atrás, gostaria de implementar nele um *time* no canto superior da tela (de qualquer lado) mas sempre acabo bugando todo game!

Aqui a função que da `Start` no game, penso em implementar a dificuldade após conseguir adicionar esse *time* na tela:

```
function newGame() {
    block = 0
    angle = 2
    tempX = 0
    tempY = 0
    square = 0
    squareTop = 0
    squareLeft = 0
    squareMotion = 1
    nextScore = 0
    score = 0
    count = 0
    collisionOne = 0
    collisionTwo = 0
    collisionThree = 0

    clearTimeout(timeoutOne)
    clearInterval(intervalOne)
    clearInterval(intervalTwo)
    document.getElementById("square0").style.left = "0px"
    document.getElementById("square0").style.top = "0px"
    document.getElementById("square0").style.display = "block"
    document.getElementById("square1").style.left = "0px"
    document.getElementById("square1").style.top = "0px"
    document.getElementById("square1").style.display = "block"
    document.getElementById("pad").style.top = (gameHeight - 40) + "px"
    document.getElementById("pad").innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("notepad").innerHTML = ""

    intervalOne = setInterval("playGame()", speed)
  }
```

Segue o Game funcionando:

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/egxjq27b/)

A Ideia inicial é implementar um *time* que se inicie ao clicar em Jogar!
Ainda tem alguns bugs... pouca experiência ainda rsrsrs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue um exemplo simples de implementação.

`div` para apresentar o tempo:

```
  <div style="z-index:1; 
              background:rgb(50, 50, 255); 
              opacity: 0.7; 
              width:70px; 
              height:20px;">
  <p id="display_tempo" style="font-color:black; text-align:center;"></p>
  </div>
```

Variáveis:

```
// início do jogo
var tempo = 0;

// referência ao timer
var tempo_controle = 0;

// está parado (=1) ou não (=0)
var parado = 1;
```

Uma função para atualizar o `div` do tempo:

```
function atualiza_tempo()
{
    if (parado)
        return;
    var tempo_segundos = Math.floor((+new Date() - tempo) / 1000);
    var display = tempo_segundos.toString() + " seg";
    document.getElementById("display_tempo").innerHTML = display;
    return;
}
```

No final do da função `newGame()` (início do jogo), iniciar a contagem de tempo:

```
...
tempo = +new Date(); 
parado = 0;
atualiza_tempo();
tempo_controle = window.setInterval(atualiza_tempo, 600);   
...
```

No último bloco da função `checkCollision()` (quando ocorre a colisão), parar o cronômetro:

```
window.clearInterval(tempo_controle);
parado = 1;
```

Obs: há outras formas (mais precisas ou com maior compatibilidade) de implementar esse cronômetro.

[Veja funcionando no jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gomiero/tv4oosgm/)